# Loading JSON file within custom node package

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I have a JSON file within my custom node package. When I run the code as an app it works fine and loads. If I install the package as a module in say a React app the path is wrong and I get a 404. I tried to use the path module to sort this but its just returning the same URL but it needs to reference the local file in the custom node package instead.

```
/**
* injects the json
* @returns {Promise<void> | *}
*/
loadModels() {
    const manifest = path.resolve('somefolder/myfile.json');
    return someClass.loadFile(manifest)
        .then(() => {
            // do stuff
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(`Unable to load JSON: ${error}`);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: what is the actual path? ie. 'somefolder/myfile.json' is supposedly './blah' ?

Comment: @HappyMachine that's relative to the script. So, the JSON file I am trying to load is in a sub folder.

Comment: @RobC Yep, it always points at the absolute path and not relative to the node_module. Surely this can be done though!! The path just resolves to: `/some_folder/myfile.json`